# How to make docker container use port other than 80

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I try to deploy self hosted Bitwarden service: https://bitwarden.com/help/article/install-on-premise/

When I run install script I get the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity 
on endpoint certbot 
(393789b88f2a15db0ae5fb0d3fdce83e14bd4d4eb890ffff0f946dc607953815): Error starting 
userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Which is expected because I already have NGINX on this VM with a couple of websites and port 80 is being used by the host.

I heard that is is possible to make docker container use another host port, instead of 80. That is container will have port 80, but it will be something else externally on the host. I tried to change the mapping in the install script like 5000:80 instead of 80:80 but I keep getting the same error.

Am I doing something wrong, or what I am trying to do is not possible?

Comment: Can you share how are you mapping the ports in dockerfile or the docker command?

Comment: it is this run.sh script https://pastebin.com/g9jYrvFj

Comment: docker run -it --rm --name certbot -p 80:80 -v $OUTPUT_DIR/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt/ certbot/certbot \
                certonly --standalone --noninteractive  --agree-tos --preferred-challenges http \
                --email $EMAIL -d $DOMAIN --logs-dir /etc/letsencrypt/logs

Comment: Strange problem - when I make a change in this file and run it - file is reverted to its original state - nothing saved. But I use sudo nano to edit it !!!!

Comment: And I am root user

Comment: did you try running `docker ps` command and see what ports are used by existing running containers??

Answer (score 1):

You can add range to the command and it will use the first available port.
so `-p 80-100:80`.

TO get the port that your actually mapping to use `docker ps` and it will show you what port it's mapped to.